# How to plot the STFT of a .wav file in GNU Octave?

Tags: stft, octave, visualization

I'm quite new to signal processing and am trying to find the short time fourier transform of an audio sample and plot it (I believe the best way is as a spectogram?) using Octave (similar to [this](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1698080-what-is-the-default-normalization-in-plot-of-stft-function-in-short-time-fourier-transform) MATLAB example).

I haven't gotten very far, I've successfully plotted the fft to get more familiar with MATLAB but I'm now stuck.

```matlab
pkg load signal

[audio, Fs] = audioread("file.wav")
[matrix, args] = stft(audio, 512, win_type=1) %win_type 1 means hanning

% [y, c] = stft (x, …) returns the entire STFT-matrix y and a 3-element vector
% c containing the window size, increment, and window type
% from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1698080-what-is-the-default-normalization-in-plot-of-stft-function-in-short-time-fourier-transform)

% plot(matrix???)
```

Comment: https://octave.sourceforge.io/signal/function/specgram.html

Comment: @Jdip how does specgram differ from STFT? Do they ultimately accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Yep, they do. `specgram` does the plotting for you if you don't specify any return arguments.

Comment: This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RURmuXMWjqQ) covers exactly what you're looking to do.